# On a ratio between a number and it's totient

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I've been having a bit of a problem with a certain ratio:  $ n / \phi(n) $ . While I understand the concept of toitient and the # of relatively prime numbers to n, I have a hard time in figuring out a large number for this ratio to come off of as. This is a bit of a two pronged question with 1. What number could increase this ratio to the point where its more than 10 and how would one find it? (I've tried looking at primes) 2. How would one prove that this number reaches positive infinity?

Comment: the way you have written this, the large values of this come when $n$ is a primorial, that is $n = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot \cdots p_r$ is a product of consecutive primes beginning with $2.$ Try you ratio for 2, then 6, then 30. This problem does require some background in number theory, though. Recommend the book by Hardy and Wright for particulars.

Comment: theorem 429 (Mertens), theorem 328 (Landau)

Comment: I see. I see. I'll go find the book and look that up. Hmm, while I'm here I might as well ask, if there are any specific chapters or sections that would be useful for a good refresher on someone in the Computer Science field that aren't in any other books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 \ne x \in (-1,1)$, then the limit

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^n x^j $$

exists, and is equal to $\frac{1}{1-x}$.  Then $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1 - p_i^{-1}} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k (\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} p_i^j) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} p_i^j$$

where we have used the fact that the limit can be interchanged with a finite product of sequences.  Now,

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1 + p_i^{-1} + p_i^{-2} + \cdots + p_i^{-n}) = \sum\limits_{(m_1, ... , m_k)} \frac{1}{p_1^{m_1} \cdots p_k^{m_k}}$$

where the sum runs through all $k$-tuples $(m_1, ... , m_k)$ such that $0 \leq m_i \leq n$.  Letting $n$ go to infinity, we see that the product $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}$ is the convergent sum $\sum\limits_{(m_1, ... , m_k)} \frac{1}{p_1^{m_1} \cdots p_k^{m_k}}$, where the $m_i$ are arbitrary nonnegative integers.

The terms $\frac{1}{d} : d \in \mathbb{N}$ are in bijection with the terms $\frac{1}{p_1^{m_1} \cdots p_k^{m_k}}$, where $k \geq 1$ and $m_1, ... , m_k \geq 0$; this is the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Then the limit as $k$ goes to infinity of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}$ is the same as the limit $m$ goes to infinity of $\sum\limits_{d=1}^{m} \frac{1}{d}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can choose a sequence of integers $n(k)$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{n(k)}{\varphi(n(k))} = \infty$ by letting $n(k)$ be the product of the first $k$ prime numbers.  If $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots$ are all the prime numbers, then $n(k) = p_1 \cdots p_k$, and

$$ \frac{n(k)}{\varphi(n(k))}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}$$ You can use the geometric series formula for $\frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{p_i}}$ and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to show that

$$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{p_i}} = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{i} = \infty$$

Comment: Hmm... I understand the theorem of arithmetic, but would you mind elaborating on the geometric series formula for 1/1-1/p?

Comment: I'll write a new answer with the details.